# Deploying to Heroku with submodule: Heroku didn't install the submodule

Tags: git, heroku, deployment, command-line-interface, git-submodules

It deploys the "parent" module just fine, but I'm getting 404s for the files inside the "child" module. When I use heroku run bash to manually git clone the child into the project I can see the files poopulate where they should be, but as soon as I exit the server's cli they disappear.

What am I doing wrong? I was under the impression that Heroku supported git submodules.

```
// Here's what I'm trying to describe...
//
// PARENT LEVEL APP (after initial "git push heroku master")
// - app.js
// - server.js
// - child/submodule
//   - nothing inside!
//
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found out what went wrong. I had cloned in the child repo without using "git submodule add". Once I did that everything was great!